# Why does flex-box overflow through the wrapper?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

I am building a responsive table based on this Codepen https://codepen.io/vasansr/pen/PZOJXr. Basically it stacks the headers and columns after a certain size, so it's readable on mobile and tablet devices, without using a scrollbar.

It's stacking but when the user tries resizing the window, the notes column doesn't stack correctly, it overflows outside the CenterOurTable div.

To give you an example of the problem, here is the codepen:https://codepen.io/laurens-van-oorschot/pen/BaaZjxO.

HTML:

```
<div id="CenterOurTable">
  <div class='container-fluid' style='margin-top: 10px'>
    <div class="table-row header">

      <div class="wrapper attributes">

        <div class="wrapper teacher-class-type-day-times">
          <div class="wrapper teacher-class-type">
            <div class="column  teacher">

              <a class="headerselect" href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> Teacher </div><div class="column evenrowcolor class-type"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Class-type </div>

      </a></div>
            <div class="wrapper day-times">
              <div class="column evenrowcolor day"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Day </div><div class="column  times"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Times </div></a></div>
              <div class="wrapper venue-location-notes">
                <div class="wrapper ">
                  <div class="column  venue"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Venue </div><div class="column evenrowcolor location"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Location </div><div class="column  notes"><a class="headerselect" href="#">Notes </div></a></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='container-fluid' style='margin-top: 10px'>
            <div class="table-row ">
              <div class="wrapper attributes">
                <div class="wrapper teacher-class-type-day-times">
                  <div class="wrapper teacher-class-type">
                    <div class="column  teacher">Julie Webb <i class="material-icons add box" style="
    vertical-align: top !important;">
add_box</i><span class="hideinfo"><ul><li><a href='mailto:tuttifruttiyoga@hotmail.com'>tuttifruttiyoga@hotmail.com</a></li><li>07861 719143</li></ul></span></div>
                    <div class="column evenrowcolor class-type">General </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="wrapper day-times">
                    <div class="column evenrowcolor day">Thursday </div>
                    <div class="column  times">19.45 - 20.45 </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="wrapper venue-location-notes">
                    <div class="wrapper ">
                      <div class="column  venue">Keig Community Hall
                        <i class="material-icons box add aria-hidden=" true " style=" vertical-align: bottom !important; ">add_box</i>

</i>    <span class="hideinfo "><ul><li>Keig Community Hall</li><li>Keig</li><li>Alford</li><li>AB33 8BH
</li></ul></span></div><div class="column evenrowcolor location ">Alford </div><div class="column notes ">Drop-In Facebook tuttifruttiyogaclasses.Drop-In Facebook tuttifruttiyogaclasses. Drop-In Facebook tuttifruttiyogaclasses. Drop-In Facebook tuttifruttiyogaclasses.  </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end container -->
</div>
```

CSS (LESS)

```
/*
 * Define the widths: play around with these 
 * to get a best fit.
 */
@index-width: 0px;
@teacher-width: 240px;
@class-type-width: 250px;
@day-width: 150px;
@times-width: 150px;
@venue-width: 150px;
@location-width: 140px;
@notes-width:140px;
@icon-width: 0px;
@date-width: 0px;
@margin-width: 85px;

/*
 * Basic styles, good for a large display. Everything fits in
 * one row, no wrapping. All text based cells grow equally.
 */
// Main container - row container
.table-row {
  display: flex;          display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row;    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;     -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;

}

// Wrappers around cells and other wrappers
.wrapper {
  display: flex; display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: row; -webkit-flex-direction: row;

  justify-content:center;
}

// leaf level containers (cells): common properties 
.column {
  flex-grow: 0; -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 0; -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.material-icons{vertical-align:middle !important;}


.column:not(.teacher,.class-type,.venue,.day) {
 padding-left:0px;
}

// leaf level containers: widths
.index { width: @index-width; }
.teacher { width: @teacher-width; }
.day { width: @day-width; }
.times { width: @times-width; }
.venue { width: @venue-width; }
.location { width: @location-width; }
.notes { width: @notes-width; }
.watch, .add-class-type { width: @icon-width; }
.date { width: @date-width; }

// leaf level containers (cells): special properties 
.index {
  text-align: center;
}

.teacher {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #337AB5;
  border: 1px solid transparent;


}

.class-type {
  width: @class-type-width;
}

// these are growable text containers, with ellipsis to show truncated text
.1teacher, .1class-type {
  flex-grow: 1; -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.date {
  width: @date-width;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

/* growable wrappers */
/*
 .teacher-class-type-day-times, .attributes {
  flex-grow: 1; -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
}
*/

/*
 * Media queries: optimize for different screen widths.
 */

// Wrapper widths
@teacher-class-type-width: max(@teacher-width, @class-type-width);
@day-times-width: max(@day-width, @times-width);
@venue-location-width: max(@venue-width, @location-width);
@teacher-class-type-day-times-width: max(@teacher-width, @class-type-width,
  (@day-width + @times-width) );
@venue-location-notes-width: max(@venue-width, @location-width, 
  @notes-width);
@all-attributes-width: max(@teacher-width, @class-type-width, 
  (@day-width + @times-width), (@venue-width + @location-width));

.horizontal() {
  flex-direction: row;        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}

.vertical() {
  // Let the wrapper flex vertically, so we get 2 rows
  flex-direction: column;     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  // can't have the children grow, since this now means vertical growth
  div {
    flex-grow: 0;  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  }
}

.vertical-growing() {
  .vertical();
  > div {
    // Let immediate child divs grow horizontally, 100% to fill the wrapper
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*
 * Media breaks.
 @margin-width * 2 + 
 */

// First break: as many 2-row fields as possible. This will leave notes
// and Dates still horizontal, as they are odd numbered
@media all and (max-width: (@margin-width * 2 + @index-width
  + @teacher-width + @class-type-width + @day-width + @times-width
  + @venue-width + @location-width + @notes-width + @icon-width * 2
  + @date-width * 3) ) {

  .teacher-class-type {
    .vertical-growing();
    width: @teacher-class-type-width;
  }
  .day-times, .venue-location {
    .vertical();
  }
}

// Next: as many 3-rows as possible
@media all and (max-width: (@margin-width * 2 + @index-width
  + @teacher-class-type-width + @day-times-width
  + @venue-location-width  + @notes-width
  + @icon-width * 2 + @date-width * 3) ) {

  // Change day-report back to horizontal, keep it under teacher and class-type
  // So, we have 3 rows: teacher, class-type, day-times
  .day-times {
    .horizontal();
  }
  .teacher-class-type-day-times {
    .vertical-growing();
    width: @teacher-class-type-day-times-width;
  }

  // Line up venue, location, notes into the next column
  .venue-location-notes {
    .vertical();
  }
  // Line up all icons in one column, even though there's only two of them
  .icons {
    .vertical();
  }
  // Line up all dates in one column
  .dates {
    .vertical();
  }

   .wrapper {
    align-items:left !important;
  justify-content:left !important;
  }
}

// Last break: 4 columns: index, attributes, icons, dates
@media all and (max-width: (@margin-width * 2 + @index-width
  + @teacher-class-type-day-times-width + @venue-location-notes-width
  + @icon-width + @date-width) ) {

  // looks better with a little padding on mobile devices
  .table-row {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
     align-items:left !important;
  justify-content:left !important;
  }

  // All attributes: teacher, class-type, day-times, venue-location, notes
  .attributes {
    .vertical-growing();
    width: @all-attributes-width;
  }
  .day-times, .venue-location {
    .horizontal();
  }
  .wrapper {
    align-items:left !important;
  justify-content:left !important;
  }
}



#CenterOurTable {
 max-width:1400px !important;
 margin:0 auto; 
 display: flex;          display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
background-color:orange;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the padding on .table-row. You have table-row width set to 100% but also with padding and it will expand beyond it's container.

You can take the padding out, or set your width offsetting the padding like `width: calc(100% - 30px)`

You still have another problem after that - you have some long words in your notes column that will not break by default and they will overflow. To fix that you have to set `word-break: break-all`

EDIT:
Just to show an example if you consider restructuring your markup to make lining up the columns easier, I might do it as a container of columns, each with their header - and use `flex-basis: 140px; max-width: 140px` to do fixed widths, and flex others.

```css
.row, .col { 
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0
}

.row {
  flex-direction: horizontal
}

.col {
  flex-direction: column
}

.col:first-child {
  align-items: center
}

.notes {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div>HEADER (Flex)</div>
    <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col notes">
    <div>HEADER (Fixed 200px)</div>
    <p>has survivchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still overlapping. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I see at lower resolutions because the width is set to 140px.

If you take the width off and instead set `flex-shrink: 1` it will fit inside the container and not overflow - that is more how flexbox is intended to be used in this case, not setting fixed widths.

If you do this though - you will see what I think is more of a structural issue with your markup. You have a header row, and then a content row, within a container, and you're trying to reuse the class names between the two rows. I think you'll have a hard time lining up the columns that way...

Comment: You may find it easier to structure the markup as a container that is a row (horizontal), with columns that each contain their own header. Then you can use `flex-basis: 140px` if you want fixed widths.

Comment: @LvO92 Just edited my answer to show an alternative layout...